# Click outside and Hide Div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the simple hide div when you click on the document.  I can't seem to get it to work. I basically want the div to toggle on when you click on a button.  And then if you click anywhere else (not on the div) it toggles off.

Here is the Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
    $(document).one(function(){
        $('.show_hide').show();
    });
});
});
```

Here is the CSS  (this is the correct CSS now with the correct JQuery Below!)

```
.slidingDiv {
background-color: #FFF;
border:3px solid #000;
border-radius:0 0 15px 15px;
float:right;
height:175px;
padding:20px;
position:relative;
top:-18px;
width:300px;
z-index:100;
display:none;
}

.show_hide {

}
```

And html:

```
<div class="slidingDiv">Hello</div>
```

Any help would be awesome.

This is the whole thing I am now running including scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){ //<----shorter version of doc ready. this one can be used ->jQuery(function($){ 
      $('.show_hide').click(function(e){ // <----you missed the '.' here in your selector.
          e.stopPropagation();
          $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
      });

    $('.slidingDiv').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
       $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here in your case you need to stop the event to bubble to the parent with `.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(e){ // <----you missed the '.' here in your selector.
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
});
$('.slidingDiv').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(){
     $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
});
```

[CHECKOUT THE DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yKhfP/)

**From docs**:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

**FYI**:

I don't know this is needed to tell you or not but you should follow this way:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){ //<----shorter version of doc ready. this one can be used ->jQuery(function($){ 
      $('.show_hide').click(function(e){ // <----you missed the '.' here in your selector.
          e.stopPropagation();
          $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
      });
      $('.slidingDiv').click(function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
      });

      $(document).click(function(){
          $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: So strange.  I entered my code into fiddle and it worked, but on the actual site it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are missing the jQuery library before your script.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('.slidingDiv').hide();
   
 $('.show_hide').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
 });

 $('.slidingDiv').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });

 $(document).click(function(){
     $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
 });
    });

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` Do you have this kind of library above this script.

Comment: I added that and it still didn't work.  I get the toggle effect just fine.  I am not sure why it isn't registering the on (document) click.  I have tried it in Chrome and Firefox.  If you want to see where I am running it is on http://art-walk.co/  Click on the sign-up or log in button.

Comment: yes i see that but in page src i didn't find the closing code.

Comment: One more thing try putting your code Either in `body` or in `head` sections in the page. That is a good thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  The problem was a loading issue with my FTP.  It wasn't actually updating the page.  I had to go to the cPanel and manually add it.  I did have to change my CSS a bit, but it is working!!! you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

OP,

What you need to do is bind the `click` event to the element you want to control showing the `<div>`, and a `click` event to the `document`, to handle the hiding. With that said, it's important to use `e.stopPropagation()` on your show function, so your event doesn't bubble up the `document`, thus hiding your `<div>`;

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qYfWv/

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function (e) {
        $('div').fadeIn();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $('div').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Jai's code should work. If the code works in the fiddle and not on your site,that should mean you're not including jQuery correctly. Are you sure you're including the jQuery library in your code?

You can use a CDN such as Google's jQuery CDN. Just add this to your HTML code:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I added both of them just to make sure. i tried it individually the ajax code you linked and his code and then i tried them both together.

Comment: Are you using your own markup and js or Jai's ? Because his answer does provide the functionality that you want IMO. Does his code along with the Google jQuery CDN still not work?

Comment: I just checked your link art-walk.co  and its working on my browsers.What's the problem?

Comment: I figured it out.  It was Dreamweaver.  I thought was updating it, but apparently it never actually pushed all the changes I was making.  I had to manually add it to the cPanel and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
```

you forget show_hide is a class

Answer (score 0):

insted of binding to ´document´ bind to the dom body tag.

`$('body').on('click', function(e){/* Magic here */})`