# jQuery search toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on my website I have a div .toggle-search that if you click on it it expands to .search-expand where a search form is. This is the code in jQuery

```
/*  Toggle header search
/* ------------------------------------ */
    $('.toggle-search').click(function(){
        $('.toggle-search').toggleClass('active');
        $('.search-expand').fadeToggle(250);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.search-expand input').focus();
            }, 300);
    });
```

Now the only way to close the .search-expand is to click once again on the .toggle-search. But I want to change that it closes if you click anywhere else on the site. For an easier example I have the Hueman theme, and I'm talking about the top right corner search option. http://demo.alxmedia.se/hueman/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you http://jsfiddle.net/ your code  ?

Comment: Here is similar question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402242/click-outside-and-hide-div][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402242/click-outside-and-hide-div

Comment: Here is a similar question answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402242/click-outside-and-hide-div

Comment: I updated my answer. Please let me know if it's good for you and if you have any questions regardless my code.

Comment: That works perfect thanks! Only one additional thing. When you click toggle2 toggle 1 should close. And the other way around. Other than that you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Sorry was too quick, when you click in the search bar or anywhere in the .search-extended it shouldn't close. And like i said before, When you click toggle2 toggle 1 should close. And the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isSearchFieldOpen = false;
var $toggleSearch = $('.toggle-search');
var $searchExpand = $('.search-expand');

function toggleSearch() {
    // Reverse state
    isSearchFieldOpen = !isSearchFieldOpen;

    $toggleSearch.toggleClass('active');
    // You can use callback function instead of using setTimeout
    $searchExpand.fadeToggle(250, function() {
        if (isSearchFieldOpen) {
            $searchExpand.find('input').focus();
        }
    });
}

$toggleSearch.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    toggleSearch();
});

$(document.body).on('click', function(e) {
    if (isSearchFieldOpen) {
        var target = e.target;
        // Checking if user clicks outside .search-expand
        if (!$searchExpand.is(target) && !$searchExpand.has(target).length) {
            toggleSearch();
        }
    }
});
```

> I have a second search on the site with the same code as before only
>   with div .toggle-serach2 and .expand-search2, how can i make your code
>   so it wont overlap. just changing the name to $('toggle-search2')
>   doesn't cut it

in that case, I would suggest you convert your code into a plugin:

```
(function($, document) {

    var bodyHandlerAttached = false;
    var openedForms = [];
    var instances = {};

    var defaults = {
        activeClass: 'active'
    };


    function ToggleSearch(elem, options) {
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.$btn = $(options.toggleBtn);

        this.isOpen = false;
        this.id = generateId();

        this.bindEvents();

        instances[this.id] = this;

        if (!bodyHandlerAttached) {
            handleOutsideClick();
            bodyHandlerAttached = true;
        }
    }

    ToggleSearch.prototype = {
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.$btn.on('click', $.proxy(toggleHandler, this));
        },

        open: function() {
            if (this.isOpen) { return; }

            var _this = this;

            this.$btn.addClass(this.options.activeClass);
            this.$elem.fadeIn(250, function() {
                _this.$elem.find('input').focus();
            });

            openedForms.push(this.id);
            this.isOpen = true;
        },

        close: function(instantly) {
            if (!this.isOpen) { return; } 

            this.$btn.removeClass(this.options.activeClass);

            if (instantly) {
                this.$elem.hide();
            } else {
                this.$elem.fadeOut(250);
            }

            openedForms.splice(openedForms.indexOf(this.id), 1);
            this.isOpen = false;
        },

        toggle: function() {
            if (this.isOpen) {
                this.close();
            } else {
                this.open();
            }
        }
    };

    var toggleHandler = function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        this.toggle();
    };

    var handleOutsideClick = function(e) {
        $(document.body).on('click', function(e) {
            if (openedForms.length) {

                var target = e.target;
                var instance;

                for (var id in instances) {
                    instance = instances[id];

                    if (!instance.$elem.is(target) && !instance.$elem.has(target).length) {
                        instance.close(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    function generateId() {
        return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);
    }


    $.fn.toggleSearch = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, 'toggleSearch')) {
                $.data(this, 'toggleSearch', new ToggleSearch(this, options));
            }
        });
    };

})(window.jQuery, document);
```

And then use it like this:

```
$('.search-expand').toggleSearch({
    toggleBtn: '.toggle-search'
});

$('.search-expand2').toggleSearch({
    toggleBtn: '.toggle-search2'
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/or287orz/)

Comment: I have a second search on the site with the same code as before only with div .toggle-serach2 and .expand-search2, how can i make your code so it wont overlap. just changing the name to $('toggle-search2') doesn't cut it.

Comment: But how then closing form by clicking outside them supposed to work? Should it just close all forms?

Answer (score 3):

Add the event on all elements except the search area.

```
$('body *:not(".search-expand")').click(function(){
    $('.toggle-search').removeClass('active');
    $('.search-expand').fadeOut(250);
});
```

or another way,

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.className.indexOf('search-expand') < 0){
        $('.toggle-search').removeClass('active');
        $('.search-expand').fadeOut(250); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a click handler to the main window that removes the active class:

```
$(window).click(function(){
  $('.toggle-search').removeClass('active');
}
```

and then prevent the class removal when you click inside of your toggle-search elem

```
$('.toggle-search').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  // remainder of click code here

)};
```

Comment: I would settle for this alternative, actually. It feels more intuitive than checking for the event target, but that's just my opinion of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `body` click listener

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('.toggle-search')) return;
    $('.toggle-search').removeClass('active');
    $('.search-expand').fadeOut(250);
});
```